# ASTM 1381-02 Serial Interfacing with Medical Lab equipment

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx, mirth

Has anybody successfully interfaced Medical Lab devices like Cell Counters /ABG instruments to mirth connect using ASTM 1381-02 or similar protocols over serial port. I am working on a small project. I need the data transmitted by the machine in ASTM format to a text file/ to a database and I cannot afford to pay $30000 for mirth commercial support. I need a low cost or open source solution.

I was expecting MLLP listener to be off use but it seems to work with TCP and I have to make it  work purely on serial communication.

Secondly
I tried writing ASTM serial data receiver in Java. But control characters such as ACK, STX, ETX, ETB, and other delimiters are not visible in terminals be it in Win 7 cmd or Netbeans/Eclipse console. Making me helpless in parsing the data.

Any help will in right direction be deeply appreciated.

Comment: "But control characters such as ACK, STX, ETX, ETB, and other delimiters are not visible in terminals be it in Win 7 cmd or Netbeans/Eclipse console. Making me helpless in parsing the data." So use a tool intended for the task that outputs hex as well, such as Minicom.

Comment: I've worked with the ASTM protocol some time ago. In Internet you may find many documents with its description. Of course you need some terminals that can display non-printable characters. I'm using Advanced Serial Port Monitor.

Comment: How did you end up solving this? I'm dealing with a similar problem, listening on a serial port for ABX/ASTM format messages

Comment: I have my own professional low cost solutions for this. If you need get in touch with me.

Comment: You can convert control chars to human visible chars. Even just using Mirth you can easily integrate CBC analyzer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are under **Linux** environment you may use COM port redirector to a given TCP port and use Mirth's TCP Listener to intercept that flow.

E.g., to pipe the serial port through netcat:
`netcat ipaddress port < /dev/ttyS0`

Or using *socat*: 
`socat pty,link=/dev/virtualcom0,raw  tcp:ipaddress:port&`

(check for [correct parameters](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-ttyovertcp.txt))

Comment: Is any similar solution to redirect serial port to TCP for windows?

Comment: @Nawaz: That was discussed already, for example [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/490477/windows-linux-socat-to-share-a-serial-device-over-ip).

Answer (score 0):

I recognize 2 problems:
 First, is it possible to raise an ftp service on the windows PC? if so, you only need to create a file reader addressed to ftp to capture the txt with the ASTM. 
 Second, to determine the characters of start and end of message I recommend you read the information of the provider, if you do not have it available, I suggest you use notepad ++ to see the hidden features. I hope you help.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI there is a commercial extension available that provides ASTM E1381 support: https://www.nextgen.com/products-and-services/integration-engine?extension=astm-transmission